# How do I get the glew.h & freeglut.h libraries?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, glut, freeglut

I'm new to C++ & Visual Studio and a friend sent me a file of an example project. It currently won't open due to several errors but the main 2 include the inability for the project to find the glew.h & freeglut.h libraries (shown in the image below).

[image]

How can I add these libraries and get rid of these two errors?

Comment: Have you asked your friend?

Comment: @MikelF yes I have but she's currently on holiday & cant reply

Answer (score 1):

I did a search on 'glew.h' and came up with: The OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library. This is a good place to start:

http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html

For freeglut:

http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/